# AutoCompletetextView with CursorLoader

Tags: android

I´m changing my application to use CursorLoader instead of startManagingCursor....

And I have one AutoCompleteTextView, SimpleCursorAdapter and in my setFilterQueryProvider  implementation, in "runQuery" method I have

```
    mProdutoAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

            Cursor cursor = mVendasDb.getProdutos(constraint.toString());
            startManagingCursor(cursor);
            return cursor;
        }
    });
```

How can I change this part to make it works with CursorLoader?

Should I discard  setQueryFilterProvider and use TextWatcher in the AutocompleteTextView and then call getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, bundleFilter, this)???  I have no idea how to proced!

bundleFilter would have the text came from textwatcher.

Is it ok using this aproach? Is it the best to do in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fine approach, according to the android developer website :

[Restarting a Loader :](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#restarting)

> To discard your old data, you use restartLoader(). For example, this implementation of SearchView.OnQueryTextListener restarts the loader when the user's query changes. The loader needs to be restarted so that it can use the revised search filter to do a new query:

Comment: So, how would you use a Loader to return a Cursor from the OP's `runQuery()` method?